# Ruby Selenium ignoreProtectedModeSettings not working

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem, selenium-iedriver

I am working in a office environment and security settings in IE are disabled for all the users and also we cant modify windows registry, below code to disable protected mode is not working

I am using Ruby, Cheezy Pageobject & selenium

```
Before do
  cap = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie(:ignoreProtectedModeSettings=>true,:ignoreZoomSetting=>true,:unexpectedAlertBehaviour=>"accept")

  @browser =  Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie,:desired_capabilities=>cap

  @browser.manage.window.maximize

end
```

I am getting below error message

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
./features/support/env.rb:40:in `Before'

Skipped step

Skipped step

Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "10.78.224.114" port 5554
./features/support/hooks.rb:47:in `After'

NoMethodError: undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass
./features/support/env.rb:48:in `After'
1 scenario (1 failed)
8 steps (8 skipped)
0m7.959s
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time to talk to your System Administrator.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I vehemently oppose to your comment **don't go for IE because it's driver is not good**. _IEDriverServer_ is _W3C_ compatible but yes there is a set of required configuration to work with IE. It's fine if you can't appreciate the good work but please don't abuse which doesn't suits you.